# Convert JSON String to List of Dynamic Objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Ive got a JSON string im sending from my web client to my webapi. This JSON string kind of dynamically formed.

So I want to know if there is a way if I can convert this JSON string into a list/array of dynamic objects. So can handle it along the same line as:

```
var DynamicArray = WhatEverJSONConvertor(JSONString);

for (int i = 0; i < DynamicArray.length; i++)
{
      Console.WriteLine(DynamicArray[i].AFieldInTheObject);
}
```

Is this possible? What JSON convertor would I use this to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Comment: Did you try doing as mentioned in http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures2ASPNETWebAPIInVisualStudio2012.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use [JSon.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and for your json response use  [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)  :

```
dyanmic [] jsonresponseArray= WhatEverJSONConvertor(JSONString);

for (int i = 0; i < DynamicArray.length; i++)
{
      Console.WriteLine(jsonresponseArray[i].AFieldInTheObject);
}

....
public dynamic[] WhatEverJSONConvertor(string json){
   // parse and create a dynamic type object
}
```

You need to ensure if the field exists, such as extension method could do.